# Sorting a large matrix in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a very large square matrix. I would like to find an effective way to get a few "top" (smallest or largest) values from the matrix, but keeping the rows / columns. With a smaller matrix, I could do the following:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10, nrow=10)
m <- cbind(as.vector(m), as.vector(col(m)), as.vector(row(m)))
head(m[ order(m[,1]), ])
```

However, this is not practical if the matrix is very large. Is there a better, more efficient way?

Comment: You can think of using `data.table` and `setkey` could be an option to consider. Otherwise you can think of having a custom function to get row numbers for max `n` elements from `m[,1]`

Comment: Why not just store the indexes to the original `m` and then use that to look up the column and row? That way you don't have to overwrite your original matrix. `sel <- order(m)[1:3]` and use that to subset `row(m)[sel]` and the similar `col` function.

Comment: @thelatemail: OMG, yes, so simple.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a dataframe with your matrix and then order as your preference.

Then, the best way is not look how order your matrix, but what is the best way to create a dataframe and order it.

Using the package `data.table` you can create a dataframe in a fast and memory efficient way:

```
m <- data.table(as.vector(m), as.vector(col(m)), as.vector(row(m)))
```

After that you order your data

```
m <- m[ order(m[,1]), ]
```